# Eclipse automatic todo task addition

Tags: eclipse, todo

Is there a way in eclipse to automatically add TODO task eg:-  `//TODO: TO BE TESTED` to the top of the function or class so that i can easily keep track of the changes yet to be tested ?

Answer (score 8):

Do you want to add the TODO when you generate the methods/classes? Then you could use code templates for that. Like `// TODO Auto-generated method stub` is added when you generate a method you could put any other comment on top of a method. `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Code Templates`

Or do you want to add the TODO to all methods/classes which currently do exist? Thats a bit harder, you could write a plugin which does that for you: [Eclipse JDT](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html)

If that TODO should always be created when you have modified a class or method you could also write an eclipse plugin which monitors the `CompilationUnit` in the editor. See `recordModifications()` [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/CompilationUnit.html#recordModifications%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the code templates and include the TODO comment there.  Code templates are located on the preferences dialog

> Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates

Unfortunately, this will only help for new methods and classes.